# Does a field annotated with JPA @version need getters and setters?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm creating a superclass for all my entities like this (Extends Spring's AbstractPersistable):

```
public class AbstractOCIDEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

/**
 * serialVersionUID
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6305700913094302357L;

// ===================================
// Concurrency
// ===================================

@Version
private long version;
}
```

Does the `@version` property need getters and setters?  My tests pass with the class as is, but I just want to make sure that it's solid.

TIA,
Ole

Comment: No field _needs_ getters and setters, whether it is version or normal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if field is annotated, reflection is used to get and set the field.

But if getter is annotated, filed will be get / set by getter / setter method.

Comment: As a follow-up, if you do use property-based annotations (aka annotate getters), you can still set the setter as package private or private if you want to restrict access to it from user code.  Hibernate doesn't care about the access restrictions and will still be able to invoke it.